# Configurar móvil para depurar con Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un BQ Aquaris E5 y un ordenador son sistema operativo `Windows 10`. Cuando intento probar las aplicaciones que desarrollo con [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio) en el teléfono no me aparece el dispositivo. 
Sin embargo el ordenador si que reconoce el teléfono y ya he permitido las aplicaciones de orígenes desconocidos en el móvil.
¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: piensa en instalar también usb drivers genéricos de google, tal vez sea eso, otra cuestión si te lo detecta el PC ponlo en modo compartir archivos ya que a veces se necesita eso para que sea detectado por Android Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución. Tenía que activar la depuración por usb. Para ello hay que entrar en opciones del desarrollador en ajustes. En mi móvil están escondidas. Para activarlas hay que pinchar 7 veces en el número de compilación en información del teléfono.

Comment: No olvides de marcarla como resuelta la pregunta

Answer (score 4):

Por default ningún dispositivo tiene habilitado el modo "`desarrollador`" (`Depuración USB`) a menos que sea un dispositivo estrictamente de desarrollo como los antiguos `G1`.

#### Para habilitar el modo "Desarrollador" entramos en la configuración en `Ajustes` -> `Información del Teléfono`

#### Pulsaremos 7 veces sobre la opción "`Número de compilación`", para que nos muestre el mensaje que indica podemos accesar a las opciones de "`desarrollador`".**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo activada en tu dispositivo las `“Opciones de Desarrollo`”, entramos y activamos la opción `Depuración USB`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto podemos conectar nuestro dispositivo Android y usarlo para desarrollar aplicaciones.

En ocasiones la confirmación tarda en aparecer, incluso si no aparece se puede activar y desactivar `USB Debugging` ( "Depuración por USB" ) par a que detecte el dispositivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¿qué tal? :)

De igual manera que tú, me he adentrado a la programación en Android. Como principiantes cometemos errores muy comunes. La solución a tu problema es la siguiente:

1.En tu dispositivo entra en 'Ajustes'

2.Información del dispositivo

3.En la etiquete de número de compilación presiona 7 veces. Se activará una nueva función en el menú de 'Ajustes'

4.En ajustes Ingresa a 'Opciones de Desarrollador' y activa la depuración USB ;)

Con esos pasos permitirás al entorno interactuar con tu dispositivo mediante la transferencia de información.

Como punto extra, al querer iniciar tu aplicación por primera vez desde android studio, te mandará una excepción. Para solucianarla únicamente activa `Tools`->`Android`->`Enable ABD Integration`

¡Mucha suerte! :D