# Conexion Bluetooth con android

Tags: android

Estoy trabajando en construir una plataforma que permita conectarse via bluetooth y hasta el momento he trabajado con un dispositivo marca AND pero es muy cansón.

¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de algún dispositivo que pueda usar para este caso?

Comment: Hola Daniel a que te refieres con "dispositivo AND", no querrás decir AVD? y que es "canson", saludos.

Comment: AND es el fabricante del dispositivo que uso en este momento,
disculpa "canson" es una expresion usada en colombia para referirse a algo que presenta muchos problemas. 
En este caso el dispositivo presenta muchos problmeas para registrar su vinculación lo que dificulta que sea usado por mas de un dispositivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traté de buscar el dispositivo que indicas, marca "AND" y no lo encontré:

Podría recomendarte un dispositivo que simplemente tenga en sus características de hardware que cuente con `bluetooth`, en realidad no he tenido problemas con ningún dispositivo:
http://www.gsmarena.com/

importante también debes poder [habilitar las opciones de desarrollador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3738/95) en el dispositivo.

Si quieres desarrollar y tener un "dispositivo oficial", actualmente serían los Nexus:

https://www.google.com.mx/nexus/