# No funciona File Explorer de Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Buenas tardes!!!

Me gustaría comentaros un problema que tengo. Estoy usando Windows 10 64bits y 10Gb de RAM (por si es importante dicha información ya que me dice un amigo que con Windows, Android da problemas..)

El problema reside en que cuando estoy trabajando con Android Studio y necesito usar el File Explorer del Device Monitor, resulta que me sale en blanco la pantalla... me pasa tanto en mi portatil como en mi pc de sobremesa por lo que debe ser un error de configuración mio o simplemente es Windows..

Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas!!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que correr el emulador en root. Para ello, introduce el comando `adb root` mientras el emulador está activo en cualquier consola.

Answer (score 1):

En la sección **`Devices`** debes seleccionar tu dispositivo, o dentro del Device Monitor puede seleccionar también el dispositivo.

Si no se muestra ahi es porque tu dispositivo no esta habilitada la opción "[USB Debugging"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3738/95)

Tienes que activar el Modo desarrollador de tu dispositivo y posteriormente [USB Debugging](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3738/95) para que se pueda ver en la sección Devices.

Revisa este tutorial:

---

Por default ningún dispositivo tiene habilitado el modo "`desarrollador`" (`Depuración USB`) a menos que sea un dispositivo estrictamente de desarrollo como los antiguos `G1`.

#### Para habilitar el modo "Desarrollador" entramos en la configuración en `Ajustes` -> `Información del Teléfono`

#### Pulsaremos 7 veces sobre la opción "`Número de compilación`", para que nos muestre el mensaje que indica podemos accesar a las opciones de "`desarrollador`".**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo activada en tu dispositivo las `“Opciones de Desarrollo`”, entramos y activamos la opción `Depuración USB`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto podemos conectar nuestro dispositivo Android y usarlo para desarrollar aplicaciones.

---

Habilitando esta opción puedes ver conectado tu dispositivo y la estructura de archivos se desplegaría en el File Explorer.

Comment: Si, con mi dispositivo si puedo trabajar. En este post me refiero a la configuración del emulador.