# ¿Como Configurar conexión: dispositivo fisíco Samsung GT-I91 con Android Studio.?

Tags: android-studio

disculpen tengo un problema para conectar dispositivo con Android Studio:

Ya he instalado el Driver USB, ya habilite la opción de desarrollador y dentro de ella, permitir depuración usb. Pero no logro hacer la conexión, no es detectado el dispositivo ni manda algún mensaje para iniciar la depuración o algo así.

Gracias, Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo verifiques si al activar la depuración USB se instala un driver. En ocasiones simplemente tiene que activar y desactivar para que muestre la ventana de confirmación para depuración USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya activaste el ["modo desarrollador" y "depuración usb"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3738/95).

- Asegura funcione el cable USB correctamente.
- Asegura el driver de tu dispositivo este instalado correctamente.

Debe mostrarte esta pantalla para que puedas permitir la depuración USB en tu pc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo verifiques si al activar la depuración USB se instala un driver. En ocasiones simplemente tiene que activar y desactivar la depuración USB para que muestre la ventana de confirmación que se muestra en la imagen.

Comment: de acuerdo, disculoe, ¿a que driver se refiere y como e puede instalar en el dispositivo físico?

Comment: me refiero al driver que se instala en la pc para lograr la conexión.

Comment: de acuerdo, verificaré.  Gracias.
Si no tengo ningún CD para instalarlo, ¿se puede descargar el driver?

Answer (score 0):

Yo mire un tutorial en youtube y en el video tanbien activa la opcion "permitir ubicaciones simuladas" activala aver que pasa , espero le encuentres solucion

Comment: Esto realmente es un comentario y no una respuesta.