# Error al ejecutar una aplicación en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, adb

[image: Este es el error que me sale al momento de ejecutar mi app]

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et1;
    private EditText et2;
    private TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_num1);
        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_num2);
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_resul);

    }


    public void Sumar(View view){
        String valor1 = et1.getText().toString();
        String valor2 = et2.getText().toString();

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(valor2);
        int suma = num1 + num2;

        String result = String.valueOf(suma);
        tv1.setText(result);

    }
}
```

*Nota: Estoy usando un dispositivo virtual no un dispositivo fisico.

Comment: Si estás trabajando con un dispositivo virtual y no arranca la aplicación, puedes intentar eliminar el dispositivo virtual y crear uno nuevo, si el problema persiste puedes cambiar el modelo ya que indica que el modelo que usas no está autorizado por lo tanto no lo detecta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la pc no tiene la autorización para instalar el apk.
Al conectar el dispositivo al pc, tienes que aceptar el diálogo de autorización.

Si no te sale el diálogo puedes intentar esto:

```
1. desconecta el dispositivo
2. adb kill-server
3. adb start-server
4. conecta el dispositivo y acepta la autorización
```

Comment: Con Android Studio 3.0 o posterior no es necesario terminar el adb, solo se tiene que conectar y desconectar el dispositivo.

Comment: Pero el problema es que estoy trabajando con un dispositivo virtual, no con uno fisico.

Comment: Quizás sea la configuración con la que creaste el dispositivo virtual. Intenta creando otro. Y también asegúrate de tener habilitado el 'ADB integration' (Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration).

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente asegura tener activado el "modo desarrollador" en tu dispositivo, y habilita el modo debug:

[Configurar móvil para depurar con Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/configurar-m%C3%B3vil-para-depurar-con-android-studio/3738#3738)

Debes autorizar el certificado al conectar via USB tu dispositivo. Si no lo autorizas tendrás el error:

> com.android.ddmlib.AdbcommandRejectedException: device unauthorized

Al conectarlo veras una ventana que indica el RSA key , debes aceptarlo para poder realizar debuggin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que se muestre nuevamente asegura tener habilitado el "modo debug" desconecta y conecta el dispositivo.

Comment: Estoy trabajando con un dispositivo virtual, no con uno fisico
Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle permiso a tu dispositivo movil para poder instalar la APK.
Tal vez todavia no lo programaste en modo desarrollo, para ello debes a tu dispositivo movil, ingresar al menú->ajustes-> darle clic 5 veces a soporte, asi te pone como desarrollador.
Despúes enchufa tu móvil y en android studio te va a salir para que puedas ejecutar tus aplicaciones.

Comment: Estoy trabajando con un dispositivo virtual, no con uno fisico
¿Como podría solucionarlo?