# Porque android studio no detecta mi dispositivo

Tags: android, android-studio

Ya lo puse en modo **depuración** se suponen que después debe aparecer la ventana para permitir huella, pero no sale nada, alguien sabe que se debe? ya intente de todo, reinstalar los drivers, MTP, PTP y nada. Lo detecta el equipo sin problema, pero no me permite autorizar.

Ver paso 3:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Version de android 6.0 - 
Tablet HYUNDAI*

Comment: seria bueno que indiques cual es tu OS.

Comment: Cual es tu dispositivo?

Comment: ya he agregado los detalles.

Comment: Generalmente tienes que autorizar la depuración en varias partes del dispositivo.

Comment: Un poco más desglosado a lo que te refieres @A.Cedano

Comment: Por ejemplo en `Ajustes adicionales -> Opciones del Programador` debes activar las siguientes opciones: `Opciones de desarrollador`,  `Depuración por USB`, `Instalar vía USB`, `Verificar aplicaciones por USB`... puede que los nombres de opciones no sean exactamente los mismos según el dispositivo, pero no creo que difieran demasiado si es que hay diferencias. **También**, debes estar atento cuando conectas el dispositivo por USB, suele salir una pantalla de autorización que debes aceptar la 1ª vez que instalas la app. Esa pantalla dura sólo un tiempo, debes aceptar antes de que se cierre.

Comment: Como comenta Cedano, si activaste el modo depuración https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/configurar-m%C3%B3vil-para-depurar-con-android-studio/3738#3738  entonces al conectar tu dispositivo debe mostrarse la ventanita para aceptar la depuración https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL1oY.png se muestra? @Even

Comment: según en el enlace de la imagen que adjuntas me falta el paso 3 es lo que no sale.

Comment: @Even asegura los pasos que comento en mi respuesta.

Comment: Siempre puedes irte al terminal para asegurarte que en realidad el ordenador lo detecta. Abre el terminal y escribe `adb devices`, si te lo detecta te debe salir una linea de numeros y letras seguido de la palabra device, de no ser así no te está detectando el teléfono

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que tienes activado el modo desarrollador, estas son las posibles causas por la cual no se puede mostrar la pantalla donde permites la depuración:

- No tienes activado el modo de depuración USB. Asegura este activado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- El driver no funciona, necesitas asegurar el correcto funcionamiento del Driver, revisa que tu dispositivo este conectado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- El cable no funciona adecuadamente. Revisa que tu dispositivo este conectado.
- El adb no funciona adecuadamente o tuvo un error, para esto puedes reiniciar Android Studio o tu PC.
- En ocasiones tarda un poco en mostrar el mensaje de dialogo por lo que te sugiero desactivar y activar el modo debug.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asegura los puntos anteriores para que puedas realizar depuración desde tu dispositivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Si el dispositivo ya está en modo depuración y no aparece la ventana para permitir huella, entonces debes verificar si la computadora tiene el USB driver instalado para que pueda detectar tu dispositivo correctamente, si tu dispositivo android es Samsung te dejo un link donde puedes descargar lo necesario.

https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/android-usb-driver.html

Si tu tablet es HYUNDAI te dejo el siguiente link

https://www.driverguide.com/driver/company/Hyundai_IT/USB/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes tu dispositivo móvil en modo depuración tienes que ir a una caja con una flecha azul apuntando para abajo es una opción al lado derecho de tu Android studio el que te mostrare en una imagen, tendrás que ir a Android SDK de ahí un apartado que dice SDK Tools verificar que tengas instalado Google USB Driver sino lo tienes instálalo y tú dispositivo debe funcionar con Android studio.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]