# Application Installation Failed y Session 'app': Error Installing APK

Tags: android

Es la n-ésima vez que tengo que lidiar con este error, sigo sin entender

1. ¿Por qué ocurre?
2. ¿Como arreglarlo? Para poder continuar emulando
       siempre tengo que rehacer todo el proyecto...
3. ¿Como evitarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparece este error:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE] $ adb shell pm uninstall
>   com.uninorte.edu.co.tracku Unknown failure: Exception occurred while
>   executing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package:
>   com.uninorte.edu.co.tracku at
>   com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4400) at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:21424)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:18498)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:913)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:912)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:134)
>   at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96) at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21727)
>   at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:573) at
>   android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:473) at
>   android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2644)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3485)
>   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674) Error while
>   Installing APK

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje se muestra

> INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE

, es debido a que al tratar de instalar el .APK, tienes una versión de la aplicación que fue creado con una firma diferente.

Por ejemplo si tenias instalada la aplicación que fue firmada para Google Play Store y tratas de instalar desde Android Studio la misma aplicación pero esta generalmente esta creada con una firma de "debug".

---

Si deseas evitar que se muestre el mensaje, habilita el [modo desarrollador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/configurar-m%C3%B3vil-para-depurar-con-android-studio/3738#3738) de tu dispositivo:

[Configurar móvil para depurar con Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/configurar-m%C3%B3vil-para-depurar-con-android-studio/3738#3738)

Ve a "Developer Settings" y deshabilita "verify apps via USB".