# Android Studio Flutter No Device

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

soy principianteen Flutter.

Mi problema es que AndroidStudio no me reconoce el dispositivo en Flutter.

Para Java y Kotlin anda bien, pero para Flutter no me lo reconoce.

Desde **flutter doctor** esta todo bien. Ya he corrido APPs en Java y en Kotlin en mi dispositivo.

Pero ahora quiero comenzar con Flutter y no puedo solucionar este inconveniente. Adjunto imágenes

[image: Flutter en AS]

[image: Flutter Doctor]

Answer (score 0):

En consola aparece en dispositivo , ve si es posible con estos comandos .

```
flutter devices
```

y después con el id del dispositivo

```
flutter run -d (id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedo notar que tu dispositivo "SM-J700M" esta conectado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Asegura que tienes habilitadas las opciones de desarrollo y habilitado USB Debugging.**

[Configurar móvil para depurar con Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/configurar-m%C3%B3vil-para-depurar-con-android-studio/3738#3738)

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero estoy 99% seguro, porque incluso ejecute una APP ayer desde AS tambén echa en Kotlin y se lanzo correctamente

Saludos

Comment: Ok puedes activar y desactivar la depuración USB y en el dispositivo se mostrará que se trata de conectar, de otra forma puede ser el cable que tiene algún tipo de falla.

Comment: Tal y como menciona @Jorgesys tu dispositivo esta conectado correctamente, pero aun no a sido seleccionado. Puedes seleccionar tu dispositivo (<no devices>)?, después ejecutar flutter run

Answer (score -1):

el problema que mencionas es  porque probablemente instalaste el SDK de Android en una ruta custom; para solucionarlo debes crear la variable de entorno `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` y asignarle como valor la ruta del SDK de android.