# ¿Cómo debuggear errores en un dispositivo android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una consulta y es el siguiente:

Estoy ejecutando una aplicación en un dispositivo físico y tengo errores(Código) que debo solucionar,  que debo hacer para `debuggear` ya que estoy poniendo `breakpoint` y no entra al método.

Estoy ejecutándolo en un dispositivo físico(Móvil) y no en un emulador ya que esta consumiendo webservices.

Se requiere hacer otras configuraciones para `debuggear` desde un móvil. El móvil ya esta en modo desarrollador y el depurador ya esta activado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar depuración (debugging) puedes iniciar tu aplicación con

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> o desde el menú mediante el icono del insecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Debes asegurar también que tu dispositivo tiene activado el "modo desarrollador", para esto ve a la configuración del dispositivo, en la sección de información del software da clic 7 veces en el build number y se activara el "modo desarrollador".

`Ajustes` > `Información del Teléfono.`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa

[**Configurar móvil para depurar con Android Studio**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/configurar-m%C3%B3vil-para-depurar-con-android-studio/3738#3738)

Comment: ¿Es realmente necesario agregar esta línea `<application android:debuggable="true">` al **manifest**? Porque jamás he añadido esa línea y me ha funcionado el `debug` de manera correcta

Comment: No, actualmente ya no es necesario.