# Android studio no instala apk en movil

Tags: android

Siempre cuando realizo un proyecto lo pruebo en un movil conectado por usb al ordenador y al ejecutar la compilacion en android studio me lo instala y ejecuta en mi movil.
Pues bien desde hace unas semanas me sale este error y no le instala en el movil, incluso si lo realizo a mano, es decir, coje el ejecutable y lo paso al movil y desde alli lo instalo.

Este es el error.

> 02/10 09:09:56: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi M2003J15SC. Installation did
> not succeed. The application could not be installed:
> INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED
>
> List of apks: [0]
> 'C:\Users\delgado\AndroidStudioProjects\CofradiaGPS\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
> Installation via USB is disabled. Retry

Comment: ¿Es un dispositivo nuevo o antes habías logrado instalar la App en él? Revisa que tienes activadas las opciones de desarrollador en el equipo y supongo que antes de intentar instalar el apk habrás borrado la App instalada previamente. Verifica que no has hecho cambios en los Ajustes del dispositivo, por ejemplo, desautorizando la instalación por USB y cosas así. Con todo verificado, debes estar atento a la pantalla del dispositivo la primera vez que instalas el apk, pues suele pedirte un permiso durante unos segundos y si no autorizas el apk no se instala.

Answer (score 1):

El problema indica que la instalación vía USB esta deshabilitada (`Installation via USB is disabled`), debes activarla.

Habilita primeramente el [modo desarrollador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400464/c%C3%B3mo-debuggear-errores-en-un-dispositivo-android), en la sección de información del software da clic 7 veces en el build number y se activara el "modo desarrollador".

`Ajustes` > `Información del Teléfono.`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa : [**Configurar móvil para depurar con Android Studio**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/configurar-m%C3%B3vil-para-depurar-con-android-studio/3738#3738)

Cuando habilites el "modo desarrollador" este se mostrará en la configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde debes habilitar el modo de depuración USB (USB debugging):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando habilites la depuración USB, sube nuevamente tu .APK al dispositivo!

Answer (score 0):

Además de la respuesta anterior, habilitar en ese mismo panel de desarrollador del móvil, la opción de instalar vía USB.