# Revocar las autorizaciones de depuración de USB - Código

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

alguien me puede ayudar con lo siguiente, pasa que quiero activar la función de ***"Revocar las autorizaciones de depuración de USB"***, pero por medio de código, ¿es posible realizar esto o me estoy imaginando locuras?.

Pasa que tengo unas computadoras que están conectadas a dispositivos móviles, pero llegado cierto tiempo, estos dispositivos no me reconocen las computadoras (supongo que por los certificados de confianza), por lo que para que me reconozca de nuevo el dispositivo, tengo que ir a las opciones de **Configuración->opciones de desarrollador -> Revocar las autorizaciones de depuración de USB**, conectar el cable de nuevo y dar acceso de nuevo, ahora mi duda es ¿existe o hay alguna forma de que haga esto de forma programada cuando me sucedan esos tipos de eventos?, o ¿que me recomiendan para estos tipos de situaciones?

Nota: Hacer esto en el dispositivo móvil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La opción para "Revocar las autorizaciones de depuración de USB" son parte de las opciones de [modo desarrollador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/400473/95) y estas no pueden habilitarse/deshabilitarse medíante código.

Lo máximo que puedes lograr es abrir las opciones de modo desarrollador de esta forma:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```

Aquí el usuario tendría que ir a la opción para revocar las autorizaciones de depuración de USB.