# Android Studio no reconoce celular para debug

Tags: android, android-studio

Instalé Android Studio Artic Fox para trabajar con un proyecto que tenía olvidado hace tiempo. El problema es que no me reconoce el celular para ejecutar la APP en el dispositivo.

Estoy trabajando en Debian 10
El SDK lo tengo en /media/mtello/D255-BA59/ANDROID/SDK que es un disco secundario, el SDK lo tenía desde una instalación previa.

el adb lo tengo en /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/ y al tirar el comando `adb devices` reconoce el dispositivo móvil, también tire un `adb kill-server` y un `adb start-server`  pero continúa sin aparecerme en dispositivo en Android.

No entiendo donde podrá estar el problema

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pueden ser varias razones, en este caso suponiendo que el proceso ADB se encuentra funcionando correctamente, en listo causas:

**1.** Debes activar el [**modo desarrollador**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/400473/95) y asegurar que la opción para depuración USB se encuentra activada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2.** dentro de tu archivo `/app/build.gradle` revisa si el valor de `minSdkVersion` es menor o igual a la [versión de la API tu dispositivo](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms).

Por ejemplo si tienes definido

```
 minSdkVersion 24
```

que corresponde a [Android 7.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#7.0) y tu dispositivo tiene sistema operativo 6.0, este no será reconocido por tu proyecto.

**3.** Asegura que el driver de tu dispositivo  funciona adecuadamente, revisa:

[Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb?hl=es)

**4.** Asegura el buen funcionamiento del cable con el que tienes conectado tu dispositivo, en ocasiones es causa por la cual un desarrollador no puede visualizar su dispositivo, incluso si usas un cable inadecuado por ejemplo demasiado delgado que no es adecuado para la corriente del puerto esto puede provocar que no funcione.