# ¿Porque no puedo activar la Depuración de USB cuando el celular esta conectado? Además aunque lo tilde o lo destilde no hay modificaciones?

Tags: android, android-studio, depuración, usb, hardware

Solo puedo tildarlo o destildarlo cuando el celular Android esta desconectado, pero parece que no hace diferencia porque no puedo usar la cámara del celular como webcam por USB y por alguna razón es como si el debugger estuviera siempre desactivado, que recomiendan?

Cabe aclarar que con ese puerto puedo trasmitir archivos desde el PC al Android sin problema pero aun así no puedo usar las características del debugger (por ejemplo con el aplicaciones como Droidcam(con USB), Android Studio o aplicaciones de Unity with Android SDK)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La depuración USB debe realizarse si el dispositivo esta conectado, de otra forma no lo podrías realizar.

Primeramente debes asegurar tener activado el modo desarrollador

[Configurar móvil para depurar con Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/configurar-m%C3%B3vil-para-depurar-con-android-studio/3738#3738)

y debes obtener una ventana de confirmación para iniciar la depuración, si esta no aparece te sugiero desconectes y conectes nuevamente el dispositivo, asegura que el cable funciona correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me sale la ventana de Allow USB debugging?

Además cuando conecto a la pc la opción de USB debugging se pone mas transparente y no se puede tildar, incluso teniendo activado el modo de desarrollador (además funciona con otras opciones del mismo)

Me suena extraño que sea el cable porque con ese cable tanto la transferencia de datos como la carga son posibles, la verdad no tengo idea que hacerle...

Comment: que marca y sistema operativo es tu celular?

Comment: El celular es un LG K10 (2017)  y su Versión de Android es la 7.0